# anaconda3 2019.07 on windows 10. not installed properly

Tags: windows-10, installation, anaconda

[its when i search for anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWgaW.png)

so I started out with running the installer .exe on windows 10 64. the installation completed, but I don't find anything on the start menu. and when I search for anaconda prompt or the navigator, its just folders showing up. no .exes to run. not sure what the problem is.

Comment: A couple guesses. Perhaps you missed  marking an option to place shortcuts in your Start menu or weren't running the installation with proper permissions (i.e. as Admin). Also, while you nailed it by using a path without spaces (a good thing), on Windows you may want to avoid using a `User` folder for the installation (beyond avoiding `C:\Programs Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`). As a broad suggestion, `C:\Anaconda` or `C:\Programs\Anaconda` might work better.

Comment: Also, if you can't get the Anaconda installer to work correctly, you can always try vanilla Python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/). While Anaconda does provide some packages that aren't available on (or don't work well on) Windows or require extra compiling, there are a lot of popular cross-platform packages that don't require Anaconda. Investigating [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) may help determine if the packages you wish to use can be installed on Windows (PyPI is where `pip`, Python's primary package manager, normally pulls from).

Comment: Did you ever run in to a solution for this? I'm having the same problem after uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda3.

Comment: @Entaras yeah. the problem was with my antivirus.

Comment: @Entaras I uninstalled my antivirus. then reinstalled anaconda. since then it's running smoothly.